# Can't get JS native animate() to work with height

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, frontend

I'm trying to do scrollUp and scrollDown with a native JS `Element.animate()`. I want the element to appear smoothly from the top to the bottom. What I get is an immediate opening and delayed collapsing. If there are currently better ways to do it, I'd like to know, I'm still curious why doesn't this work though.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('addNewScriptStep').onclick = function() {
    let list = document.getElementById('collapsibleActionList');
    let newHeight = '100%';
    if (list.dataset.iscollapsed == 'false') {
      newHeight = '0';
    }
    list.dataset.iscollapsed = !eval(list.dataset.iscollapsed);
    list.animate({
      height: newHeight
    }, {
      fill: 'forwards',
      duration: 500
    });
  };
});
```

```css
#collapsibleActionList {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  transition: height 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="addNewScriptStep" class=""> Add an action </a>
  <ul id="collapsibleActionList" data-iscollapsed="true">
    <li data-type="open_url">Open URL</li>
    <li data-type="href_to">Click link</li>
    <li data-type="click_element">Click element</li>
    <li data-type="insert_into">Insert into textbox</li>
    <li data-type="sleep">Sleep</li>
    <li data-type="checked">Check checkbox</li>
    <li data-type="unchecked">Uncheck checkbox</li>
    <li data-type="send_form">Submit form</li>
    <li data-type="if_element_is_defined">Continue if HTML contains element</li>
    <li data-type="if_element_is_not_defined">Continue if HTML doesn't contain element</li>
    <li data-type="if_text_is_defined">Continue if there is text</li>
    <li data-type="if_text_is_not_defined">Continue if there is no text</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Edit: I noticed that after removing CSS transition property, the list can no longer collapse, though animate function IS being called with {height: '0'}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I transition height: 0; to height: auto; using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css)

Comment: @Yogi, thanks for the link. Sadly, after changing height to max-height and 100% to 1000px I didn't get any results, now it just doesn't even open, no matter what transition is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with useing `max-height` instead of `height` you can do it.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('addNewScriptStep').onclick = function() {
    let list = document.getElementById('collapsibleActionList');
    let newHeight = '999px';
    if (list.dataset.iscollapsed == 'false') {
      newHeight = '0';
    }
    list.dataset.iscollapsed = !eval(list.dataset.iscollapsed);
    list.animate({
      maxHeight: newHeight
    }, {
      fill: 'forwards',
      duration: 500
    });
  };
});
```

```css
#collapsibleActionList {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="addNewScriptStep" class=""> Add an action </a>
  <ul id="collapsibleActionList" data-iscollapsed="true">
    <li data-type="open_url">Open URL</li>
    <li data-type="href_to">Click link</li>
    <li data-type="click_element">Click element</li>
    <li data-type="insert_into">Insert into textbox</li>
    <li data-type="sleep">Sleep</li>
    <li data-type="checked">Check checkbox</li>
    <li data-type="unchecked">Uncheck checkbox</li>
    <li data-type="send_form">Submit form</li>
    <li data-type="if_element_is_defined">Continue if HTML contains element</li>
    <li data-type="if_element_is_not_defined">Continue if HTML doesn't contain element</li>
    <li data-type="if_text_is_defined">Continue if there is text</li>
    <li data-type="if_text_is_not_defined">Continue if there is no text</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

you can do this in a simpler way. if you want?

```js
const link = document.getElementById('addNewScriptStep')
const list = document.getElementById('collapsibleActionList')
link.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  list.classList.toggle('open')
})
```

```css
#collapsibleActionList {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.5s;
}
#collapsibleActionList.open {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 999px;
  transition: max-height 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="addNewScriptStep" class=""> Add an action </a>
  <ul id="collapsibleActionList" data-iscollapsed="true">
    <li data-type="open_url">Open URL</li>
    <li data-type="href_to">Click link</li>
    <li data-type="click_element">Click element</li>
    <li data-type="insert_into">Insert into textbox</li>
    <li data-type="sleep">Sleep</li>
    <li data-type="checked">Check checkbox</li>
    <li data-type="unchecked">Uncheck checkbox</li>
    <li data-type="send_form">Submit form</li>
    <li data-type="if_element_is_defined">Continue if HTML contains element</li>
    <li data-type="if_element_is_not_defined">Continue if HTML doesn't contain element</li>
    <li data-type="if_text_is_defined">Continue if there is text</li>
    <li data-type="if_text_is_not_defined">Continue if there is no text</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this actually works, I chose using the second variant. My mistake was using `'max-height'` property instead of `maxHeight` in the script, also using a class instead of data-iscollapsed is so much better. Would like to point out that using overflow and transition twice in .open isn't necessary, and, for future viewers, that you should set max-height of .open to the actual content length so there won't be a delay scrolling through empty pixels, in my case, 12em, and not 1000px, ironically

Answer (score 0):

`height: 100%` in this context doesn't really bring any meaning: as it's not dependent on a height of some parent element, it's basically the same as `height: auto` and you can't animate using `height:auto`. Now, considering that you are already using .js, before animating the element you can first set its innate height in pixels that you want to animate to:

```js
const ul = document.querySelector("ul")
const btn = document.querySelector("button")

//the important part:
ul.style.height = ul.scrollHeight + "px"

btn.addEventListener("click", ()=>ul.classList.toggle("open"))
```

```css
ul{
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 1s;
  background: #ddd;
}

ul:not(.open){
  height: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
<ul>
  <li>Some elements</li>
  <li>To show</li>
</ul>
```